# Openproject: How to set config/configuration.yml in docker environment

Tags: configuration, yaml, openproject

I want to configure the docker version of Open Project with the configuration.yml. Where has the file to be stored or where can I find it. None of the given external directories .asset and .pgconfig contains the yml file.

Answer (score 2):

You can mount single files into your container. So we can adjust the [example](https://docs.openproject.org/installation-and-operations/installation/docker/#recommended-usage) from the docs like this to include your own `configuration.yml`:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/openproject/{pgdata,assets}
printf "production:\n  disable_password_login: true" > /var/lib/openproject/configuration.yml

docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name openproject -e SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret \
  -v /var/lib/openproject/pgdata:/var/openproject/pgdata \
  -v /var/lib/openproject/assets:/var/openproject/assets \
  -v /var/lib/openproject/configuration.yml:/app/config/configuration.yml \
  openproject/community:11
```

This, for instance, will disable the password login in OpenProject via the `configuration.yml`. Usually you would do this via env variables (`-e OPENPROJECT_DISABLE__PASSWORD__LOGIN=true`) but there are configurations such as for SAML which are indeed easier to just define in the `configuration.yml` instead.

The file inside of the container is `/app/config/configuration.yml`.

Comment: Thanknk You. I check this out.